# Correct way to implement Discrete and Stationary Wavelet Transform?

Tags: matlab, wavelet, time-frequency

Can someone please confirm if this is indeed the correct way to compute DWT:

```
load image
load Haar wavelet

for i = 1: Level
  periodize edges of image
  convolve image with Low pass Haar wavelet filter and store result in G
  convolve image with Low pass Haar wavelet filter and store result in H

  convolve G with low pass Haar to calculate approximation co-eff
  convolve G with high pass Haar to calculate horizontal co-eff

  convolve H with low pass Haar to calculate vertical co-eff
  convolve H with high pass Haar to calculate diagonal co-eff

  i = i + 1
  downsample approximation by 2 
end
```

In case of SWT, instead of down-sampling the approximation, Haar filter co-efficients are up-sampled twice at each level and the same process is repeated. Am I correct here?

Answer (score -1):

In the Haar wavelet case, I just used the following NumPy:

```
# assume x is passed in as a variable
haar_transform = zeros(N)
i = arange(N/2, dtype=int)
haar_tranform[i]      = x[2*i] + x[2*i + 1]
haar_transform[i+N/2] = x[2*i] - x[2*i + 1]
```

I believe the mathematical description includes some scaling by $1/\sqrt{2}$.

I've learned that while academic papers may describe something very complicated there's a simple way to compute it.